# ionic not finding android

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have tried to use ionic lab. I tried to build a simple blank app using the lab but when I go to build my android app it says I need to have android sdk. I have android sdk and the platform tools already. I even added to my path in case you were wondering. I was graciously sent here to ask for help after trying to research my issue by looking at "ionic android build error - failed to find android_home".(which was when i checked my environment path). I took a screen shot of both(environment and error from ionic lab console). [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2O3Z.jpg) and 
[environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDJQJ.jpg)

Comment: Oh I almost forgot: OS - windows10, androidSDKv: 22 and 24. Ionic build android command does work though* I test this with a different project though. Maybe ionic lab is THE issue and I shouldnt use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For windows:--
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\<installation location>\android-sdk-windows
set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
The Android SDK download does not include specific Android platforms.   To run the code in this guide, you need to download and install the latest SDK platform. You do this by using the Android SDK and AVD Manager that you installed in the previous section.

Open the Android SDK Manager window:

android
Note: If this command does not open the Android SDK Manager, then your   path is not configured correctly.
Select the Tools checkbox.
Select the checkbox for the latest Android SDK.
From the Extras folder, select the checkbox for the Android Support Library.
Click the Install packages... button to complete the download and installation.

Note: You may want to install all the available updates, but be aware it will take longer, as each API level is a large download.
```

Comment: thank you sir for the windows command. Unfortunately, it did not work. No version supplied. Retrieving version from config.xml...
Adding android project... 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. i check node and did "SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Nodejs;%PATH%" still didnt work

Command finished with error code 1: cmd /s /c "C:\Users\Khanh\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\4.0.2\package\bin\create.bat --cli D:\stackFails\platforms\android com.ionicframework.stackfails867190 SimpleHello"

Comment: thanks but I've come to an answer thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Could you please do following stuff in terminal. It might be helpful for you.

```
Step:--1
export ANDROID_HOME=~/android-sdk-macosx
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools  

Step:--2
Update SDK and go to directiory and set your SDK path properly.
```

Comment: you mean command line? I'm sorry but I dont think I have terminal on windows 10